# Storing different data types in java (android)

Tags: android, xml, arrays, list

question worth million dollars for a noob like me. I would like to store a list in xml in java for android... Such as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<places>
    <id1>
        <Name>Sydney</Name>
        <Code>abc-def-ghi</Code>
        <Latitude>-33.859972</Latitude>
        <Longitude>151.211111</Longitude>
    </id1>

    <id2>
        ...
    </id2>
</places>
```

Then I would like to call it back programatically. I saw people using such construction in all tutorials all over the web, but eclipse expects Array with items.

Q1: What am I doing wrong with the XML?
Q2: How can I recall the values in the code?

Thank you all!

Ondra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the XML file in the assets folder and then check out this question, it answers how to open the file.

[android: how to load xml file from assets directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557885/android-how-to-load-xml-file-from-assets-directory)